# I have an error at line 17, in pointsPlus points += 1*mult TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'Event' and 'int'

Tags: python, helper

I keep on getting this in my console, what does it mean!?

> File "C:/Users/deus2/PycharmProjects/Testing/ClickerGame.py", line 17,
>   in pointsPlus
>        points += 1*mult
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'Event' and 'int'

```
from tkinter import *

main = Tk()
frame = Frame(main, width = 500, height = 575)

global points
global mult


points = int(0)
mult = int(1)

pointsLabel = Label(main, text = points)
pointsLabel.pack()

def pointsPlus(points):
    points += 1*mult
    pointsLabel()
    pointsLabel.update()


frame.bind('<Button-1>', pointsPlus)
frame.pack()

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: When `pointsPlus` is called, the parameter it is supplied is an Event object. That parameter goes into the `points` variable inside the function. You try and add a number `1*mult` to that Event, which does not make sense. If you want to add to your global `points` variable, change the name of the function parameter to something else.

Comment: The `global` statements are in the wrong place; they need to be inside the function where you want `points` and `mult` to be treated as global, rather than local, names.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work

```
from tkinter import *

main = Tk()
frame = Frame(main, width = 500, height = 575)

points = 0
mult = 1

pointsLabel = Label(main, text = points)
pointsLabel.pack()

def pointsPlus():
    global points  # assuming you want to modify global parameter here
    points += 1*mult
    pointsLabel()
    pointsLabel.update()


frame.bind('<Button-1>', pointsPlus)
frame.pack()

main.mainloop()
```